# What does return exactly do inside a loop?

Tags: java, return

Considering below code, what does exactly return do here? I mean which methods and loops does it make the program exit from?

```
 void foo(){
    try{
        for (String a : myList){
           while(true){
               if (myBoolean)
                   return;
           }
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
       }
 }
```

Comment: `return;` works the same everywhere except inside a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `myBoolean` is true, it ends the loop, and everything else that was going on (no Exceptions to consider) and returns control to whatever function called `foo()`.

In your usage `return;` it refers to functions that have a return type of `void`. Since there is nothing to return, it just stops everything that was going on *in that function*.

EDIT:

One thing to note here is that the OP has mentioned a `try-catch` block. If instead, there was a `try-catch-finally`, or `try-finally` block, it would first hit that finally block before returning. In the snippet below, 
although the `return` is evaluated, `Hit finally` is printed. Try it out :)

```
try {
    if (0 == 0)
        return;
} finally {
    System.out.println("Hit finally");
}
```

Why does this happen? 
The `finally` block is where a lock is released. It **MUST** hit in order to prevent resources from being leaked which would happen if control is allowed to leave a synchronized region without releasing the lock.

Aha. There is a way to fool this too. Look at this infinite loop.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (0 == 0)
            return;
    } finally {
        continue;
    }
}
```

I think this is enough for this question. I'll stop now.

Comment: My main question was whether it ends foo or not. and i got the answer. thanks.

Comment: @solo Yes, boss. It sure does. :)

Comment: I think you might be thinking of break;? "return" takes you out of the method entirely. Java more-or-less never has nested methods, so there's no ambiguity there.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yea yea. That's what I wrote, or intended to write. Should I re-word?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Well java behaves try-catch as methods in some cases which made the ambiguity to me.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is bringing you out of the method, even if the method return void, you will return to the original invoker when the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

when control reach to `return` statement it will return to caller-end without any exception(so it won't go to `catch`  block ) ,

> but for your reference i add more on it, if in case `finally` block is
>   there then it must return to caller-end through `finally`
>   block(because as we know finally block always execute in any case)

Answer (score 0):

`return` exits the method `foo`.

If you want to exit the `while` loop, use `break` (which takes you out of the innermost loop).

If you want to break out of the `for` loop, use a labeled break:

```
label:
for (String a : myList) {
    ...
    break label;
```

Comment: No problem. It's occasionally useful but don't use it too much.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have said, when `myBoolean` is true, the `return` statement will cause the `foo()` method to end, and control to return to the method that called `foo()`.

Just to expand the answer, `break` and `continue` could also be used in a loop, depending on the desired behaviour. The `break` statement will cause the loop to end with execution continuing immediately after the loop.

If you want to skip to the next iteration of the loop you can use `continue`.